# Sodium event updates not being reflected

Tags: haskell, frp

So I'm trying to understand how Sodium's model for functional reactive programming works, and I'm running into some snags.
I have a list of numbers that I'm updating with a "Time" like value, and I'm adding to this list when space characters are passed in.
The engine that runs this is as follows.

```
import FRP.Sodium

type Time = Event Int
type Key  = Event Char
type Game a = Time -> Key -> Reactive (Behavior a) 

run :: Show a => Game a -> IO ()
run game = do
    (dtEv, dtSink)   <- sync newEvent
    (keyEv, keySink) <- sync newEvent
    g <- sync $ do

        game' <- game dtEv keyEv
        return game'

    go g dtSink keySink
    return ()
  where
    go gameB dtSink keySink = do
        sync $ dtSink 1

        ks <- getLine
        mapM_ (sync . keySink) ks

        v <- sync $ sample gameB
        print v

        go gameB dtSink keySink
```

So with this I'm printing the current value the game behavior gives every "tick". Here is the code for the game behavior.

```
main :: IO ()
main = run game


game :: Time -> Key -> Reactive (Behavior [Int])
game dt key = do
    let spawn = const 0 <$> filterE (==' ') key

    rec
        bs <- hold [] $ snapshotWith (\s xs -> (s:xs)) spawn updated 

        updated <- hold [] $ snapshotWith (\t xs -> map (+t) xs) dt bs


    return updated
```

What I'd expect this to do is with every space character inputted, a `0` gets injected into the list.
Effectively, every time enter is pressed, I'd expect all the numbers in the list to increment by one.
Instead what happens the numbers increment only after I press space.
Does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

After some more thought, it's pretty obvious what the problem was.
The issue with my code is that I have this circular dependence that doesn't take into account the fact that the each behavior also depends on its own changes.
This meant that whenever I tried to add things to the list it'd take the old value of the list given by the time update to change the value, until the time value changed.
To rectify this problem, I restructured the `game` behavior to merge the update and spawn events like so.

```
data GEvent = Alter ([Int] -> [Int])

game :: Time -> Key -> Reactive (Behavior [Int])
game dt key = do
    let spawn = const (Alter (\xs -> (0:xs))) <$> filterE (==' ') key
        update = (\t -> Alter (\xs -> map (+t) xs)) <$> dt
        applyAlter (Alter f) xs = f xs

    rec
        bs <- hold [] $ snapshotWith applyAlter (merge spawn update) bs 


    return bs
```

This ensures that when either event occurs that they get the most up to date version of the list.